# Адаптивный макет.Разместить блок по вертикали чтобы сохранилась адаптивность по высоте

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, float

Такая задача - нужно сделать макет адаптивный под мобильный экран без использования flex и grid "Holy Grail". Есть такая проблема - как сделать чтобы когда контента становится много блок растягивался с ним, а не уходил за следующий блок. Прошу помощи.

Css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(43, 29, 250);
  clear: both;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgb(255, 114, 14);
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.main {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.link {
  background-color: darkmagenta;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  background: green;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
      height: calc(100% - 80px);
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  p {
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 10px;
      height: auto;
  }

  .nav {
      background-color: rgb(255, 114, 14);
      height: 10%;
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      padding: 4px;
  }

  .main {
      background-color: chartreuse;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80%;
      float: left;
  }

  .link {
      background-color: darkmagenta;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10%;
      float: left;
  }
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Task_1</title>
<link href="../floats/float.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="wpapper">
    <div class="clearfix">
   <div class="header">
     <div class ="inner-header">
       <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
   </div>


      <div class="nav">
        <div class="inner-nav">
          <h1>Navigation</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main">
        <div class="inner-main">
          <h1>Main</h1>
          <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="link" >
        <div class="inner-link">
          <h1>Related links</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   <div class="footer">     
     <div class ="inner-footer">
       <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Такое задание нужно выполнить.

Answer (score 0):

Вот эти файлы

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(43, 29, 250);
  clear: both;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  background-color: rgb(255, 114, 14);
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.main {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.link {
  background-color: darkmagenta;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  background: green;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: rgb(255, 114, 14);
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
  }
  .main {
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    float: left;
  }
  .link {
    background-color: darkmagenta;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Float</title>
  <link href="../floats/float.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <h2>Navi</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <h2>Main</h2>
      <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
        voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
        modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
        qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
      <h2>Related links</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```